# Difference between Set-WebConfiguration and Set-WebConfigurationProperty cmdlets

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to automate creation/modify of application and virtual directory with authentication and ssl setting flags using powershell. However, I find **Set-WebConfiguration** and **Set-WebConfigurationProperty** cmdlets confusing. I didn't find much details in microsoft docs. Please anyone can suggest if there is any difference in usage of both cmdlets? Or I can use both of those interchangeably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using cmdlets to set Ssl flags. One of the key difference is that **Set-WebConfiguration** auto-generate parent element if those are missing. However,  **Set-WebConfigurationProperty** doesn't perform that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know much about powershell. But based on their documentation, I don't think they are the same thing.

First of all, the introduction to the documentation already shows that they apply to different objects: **element** and **property** of IIS Configuration.

And the former (Set-WebConfigurationProperty) supports and uses wildcards, while the latter (Set-WebConfiguration) does not.

And they also contain different [command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/set-webconfigurationproperty?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters), like `-AtElement`, `-AtIndex` and `AtName`.

All that said, I think they should be used to implement different needs, and you need to differentiate between them.

Comment: If you see the example for bindings of existing website, both cmdlets are used. My usecase is similar to this. Also, I have found one major difference but still testing it.